# Utilizing a third party application for GitHub in a django project

Tags: python, django, github, aptana

I'm trying to use a third party application located here:

```
git://github.com/Star2Billing/django-audiofield.git
```

I'm using Aptana Studio as my IDE. I created my project and then I clicked on the project and imported the app from the github location. It looked like it imported. I wanted to check that it imported properly before beginning any real coding so I performed *`manage.py validate`*.

I got a message that stated: `"No module named audiofield"`. I added the app to my Installed Apps settings and followed the installation instructions.

I'm not sure if I'm importing it incorrectly. Also, I'm using `virtualenv` in Aptana. I'm not sure if this may have added to the problem.

Please help.

Update: Thank you dm0351. I did what you suggested. However, I'm getting the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/home/Desktop/Web Development/Aptana Studio 3.0/musicproject/src/manage.py",    line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
 File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/validate.py", line 9, in handle_noargs
self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
self._populate()
File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 67, in _populate
self.load_app(app_name)
File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
models = import_module('.models', app_name)
File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/src/audiofield/audiofield/models.py", line 19, in <module>
from audiofield.fields import AudioField
File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/src/audiofield/audiofield/fields.py", line 20, in <module>
from tasks import audio_convert_task
File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/src/audiofield/audiofield/tasks.py", line 14, in <module>
from celery.task import Task
ImportError: No module named celery.task
Finished "/Users/home/Desktop/Web Development/Aptana Studio 3.0/musicproject/src/manage.py  validate" execution.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can install into your virtual environment using:

```sh
pip install -e URI#egg=EggName
pip install -e git+git://github.com/Star2Billing/django-audiofield.git#egg=audiofield
```